# Assigning multiple variable values to a single variable in Python

Tags: python, string, path

I have a number of variables which are set and later in my code I want to use these variables together as one single variable with a `.` separation.

For example

```
Release=1
Build=2
ServicePack=3
Hotfix=4

Directory=Release.Build.ServicePack.Hotfix
```

I understand that the above line will not work but I'm not sure how to join the variables together when declaring the last one.

In my example I would like the `Directory` variable to equal `'1.2.3.4'`.

Th end goal here is to use `os.path` to create a directory based on the value of `Directory`. Given this would a better alternative to use `os.path.join` and pass in the individual variables instead of a single one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Directory = '.'.join(str(x) for x in (Release, Build, ServicePack, Hotfix))
```

Turn each variable into a string. Join them together with a '.' in between.

```
os.path.join("path/to/base", Directory)
```

will work fine, resulting in

```
path/to/base/Release.Build.ServicePack.Hotfix
```

If I were you, I'd either use all caps for those variables, meaning they're constants, or all lower case, as specified in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly fast response! I appreciate it. I'll watch those variables name too from now on :)

Comment: The naming schema is so you can tell at a glance what the variable is. all lowercase is a variable definition, all caps is a constant, capitalized is a class definition (and some other stuff as well that I'm blanking on at the moment).